# Saving an activity state by using a save button. And loading it from a save menu

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, save, load

I want a save button to save an activity state. This should save it as a new load button in a "game type of save file screen".
Every explanation I find is for is to save and load on creation. But it should be saveable and retrievable on the user's command.

Comment: Hi Marthy, welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page and the [mcve]

Comment: What exactly do you want to save?

Comment: I have a activity that opens with a loaded image and html file. Since this loads at random I want users to be able to load this combination again after leaving this activity.